# Navigating from child page to parent page

Tags: html

Basically I have an iframe embedded in my parent page and I am navigating from parent page to child page with the help of form action and that child page shows my expected result .Now I want to display the child page in my parents's iframe.

What should i do...? peale suggest me ...

Comment: Sounds like you need to read through the [frameset spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html), and more specifically the part about the [targets](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `target` property?
`<a href="http://google.com/" target="iframe">Google</a>`
`<iframe src="http://yahoo.com" name="iframe">Your browser doesn't support iframes</iframe>`

Comment: yah i have already tried that...i think u haven't understand my problm...:( thing is i have two pages parent.html and child.html and 1) i am sending some parameters to child page from parent page ... 2)executing that child page and its gives me some result now 3) i want to display that result page in iframe embeded in parent page......